# Tips to Resolve "No living connection " on starting kibana in windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, wazuh

'''
\log   [13:36:52.255] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/
log   [13:36:52.277] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
log   [13:36:52.279] [warning][task_manager] PollError No Living connections
log   [13:36:53.810] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/
log   [13:36:53.836] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
log   [13:36:56.456] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/
log   [13:36:56.457] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
log   [13:36:56.458] [warning][task_manager] PollError No Living connections
log   [13:36:57.348] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/
log   [13:36:57.349] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connection
'''

I am getting above error while connecting to kibana through windows.. I have installed wazuh server using **`OVA image.`**

**Kibana.yml** configuration file contains all these entries:  **server.host,server.ssl,server.ssl.key,server.ssl.certificate,telemetry.enabled**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ElasticSearch is also running locally (localhost:9200):

Kibana is looking for ElastiSearch on the localhost port 9200. Verify if your ElasticSearch is running on that port by going to the browser by: http://localhost:9200

If not, and ElastiSearch is running, then verify which port ElasticSearch is running on

In any case (whether local or may container) verify the connection to ElasticSearch manually. If you can get there manually from the same environment Kibana is running on, you shouldn't get this error.